# Can`t load an simple image. Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, pixmap

I'm making a splash screen (for my game) using LibGDX.
I'm using a .png format images, and with few of them - it works (my images are properly located in the assets folder)
I'm getting this error with few of my images I want to use:

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: devlogo.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GLTexture.createTextureData(GLTexture.java:185)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:103)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:95)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:91)
    at com.GunRun.Screens.Splash.show(Splash.java:34)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.mynewgame.game.GunRun.create(GunRun.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error loading pixmap: decoder init failed for stream
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:57)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:138)
    ... 10 more
```

Code from splash screen class:

```
public class Splash implements Screen{

private Sprite devlogo;
private SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    devlogo.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture("devlogo.png");
    devlogo = new Sprite(texture);
    devlogo.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}



@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

}
```

The images with which works has 24 bit depth, and others who doesn't has 64 bit depth, can be there a problem?

Comment: 64 bit pngs are quite rare. I wouldn't be surprised if the OS can't load it. No typical computer or mobile screen can even display 48 bit color and OpenGL ES only supports up to 8 bits per channel, not 16.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks you man, I just have figure it out where the problem was - its in bit depth (I was not well informed about what is it).

I changed it throught photoshop to 8 bit depth and it word nicely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this problem recently too, so I did some digging into where that error message comes from. The error comes from [this line](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/jni/gdx2d/jpgd.cpp#L3089) in jpgd.cpp:

```
jpeg_decoder decoder(pStream);
if (decoder.get_error_code() != JPGD_SUCCESS) {
    err_reason = "decoder init failed for stream";
    return NULL;
}
```

The interesting thing there is that since these are PNGs, it's pretty suspect that it's trying to load the image as a JPG. It turns out that will happen [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/c95cecd341a5b6157b4f5e5b77db08b63b274f7f/gdx/jni/gdx2d/gdx2d.c#L224-L227) if LibGDX fails to load the image into memory on the first try:

```
const unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load_from_memory(buffer, len, &width, &height, &format, 0);
if (pixels == NULL) {
    pixels = jpgd_decompress_jpeg_image_from_memory(buffer, len, &width, &height, &format, 3);
}
```

It turned out that I was hitting this because I had a massive memory leak in part of my game, so LibGDX was simply failing to allocate memory to load the image. Fixing the memory leak corrected the problem for me.

Since this is happening on your splash screen, I'm guessing a memory leak isn't the cause of your issue, but it might be worth checking that you have enough memory allocated for the application.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to save image 8bit/channel instead of 16bit/channel.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Change the RGB profile with any photo editor (I used photoshop).

When you go to save the image, just exclude the previous RGB profile.